# Rails db not adding a new column with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my User model.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  validates :name,:presence=>true,:length=>{:maximum=>15}
    validates :email,:presence=>true,:length=>{:maximum=>15}
end
```

I wanted to add a new column of password.
I used the command

```
rails g migration pass_mig password:string
```

then

```
rake db:migrate
```

but in db schema still

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130627073430) do

      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "email"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
      end
end
```

Also in Rails console :Password can not be added in a new User object i.e in a new database entry..Please suggest.
P.S: I am new to rails so this might be a silly ques. I am using rails version:3.2.13 and ruby version:1.9.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is one of those "magical" things about rails everyone is always talking about. There is a naming convention for when you do migrations to add columns to tables. Try this:

```
rails g migration add_password_to_users password:string
```

There are actually important naming conventions for nearly everything.

Comment: You should also inspect and edit any migration files produced by the generator before executing them.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot."Magical" it is. Also can you please tell the best place to learn some other magical conventions from.

Comment: user2526795 you'll want to follow the advice @tadman mentions above. And study the code that Bachan Smruty posted as well. There are multiple ways of doing most things in rails.

Comment: If you're looking for more advice on how Rails does its thing, there are many [books](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4) that might provide the sorts of examples you're looking for.

Comment: @tadman ok ..thanks.. looks like just the right thing i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can add the standalone migration as per the below

```
rails generate migration AddPasswordToUsers password:string
```

For more standalone migration you can follow the link.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

OR you can do another thing. 
1st create a migration

```
rails g migration AddColumnToUser
```

This will create a migration file in db/migrate. You need to change that file content.

```
class AddColumnToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # all the codes being generated automatically. The following you need to write.
    add_column :users, :password, :string   # this means you are adding password having string type in users table.
  end
end
```

After done with one of the steps above. just do `rake db:migrate`